# windows IoT core on screen keyboard

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

Have the latest releases to Windows IoT included an On Screen Keyboard? I am aware of other suggestions that use the webview to provide a keyboard, but I would prefer an OSK for my UWP app. Ideally internationalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Screen Keyboard is not mentioned in the latest [release 14931](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/releasenotesinsiderpreview), so the answer is no at the moment.

> Part of the reason for this is that we don’t have a ‘shell’ like
>   explorer that is there helping control what app is running or
>   providing other services such as SIP / OSK as is handled on the
>   desktop.
>
> Longer term I believe this is something that the product team is
>   considering / looking into but I do not have any timeline on if or
>   when it might be an option (if ever).

The following link is the MSDN post you can reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d81ebfa0-ccdc-479e-8e2f-bc921de17343/onscreen-keyboard?forum=WindowsIoT

**Update:**

**It is available. Please refer to** "[Windows IoT Core - On-screen keyboard for headed devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/onscreenkeyboard)".

Answer (score 6):

It is available in the latest preview release (14986). See de image bellow.
On the left the device portal, on the right a screenshot of the device.
[image: On the left the device portal, on the right a screenshot of the device]

**Edit**
About the internationalization, the only thing I've found until now is the keyboard layout option, on the device settings, but it seems to not be working yet, cause I don't see the "Ç" character that should be present in a pt-br keyboard.
[image: keyboard layout option]

Comment: Yes I spotted that. It doesn't seem to be internationalized, have you managed to find a way top change it?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the latest release the 14971? I haven't tried yet, but they mention an On-Screen Keyboard

"An On Screen Keyboard (OSK) was added as an optional package and was added to the default FFUs. The OSK is disabled by default and must be enabled via the new option in Windows Devices Portal (Web Management)."

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5244ac-bf5c-486c-a203-b0406bc858f6/new-flight-14971-released-for-insiders?forum=WindowsIoT