# Disable On-screen keyboard for a Single View

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

In Windows IoT Core, you go to the Windows Device Portal and then check the On-Screen Keyboard checkbox as seen [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288073/2093880)

[image]

In one scenario, we have two views one with a custom keyboard and the other is intended to use the standard On-Screen Keyboard.

Any idea how to disable the On-Screen Keyboard for the first view?

Comment: So you have two `TextBox`es and want to show the virtual keyboard only for one of them? Try setting `IsEnabled` to `false` on the one that shouldn't show the keyboard.

Comment: It looks like no methods to disable the On-Screen Keyboard at runtime. Based on your user case, you may try to implement two different kinds of styles keyboard applied to two views. There is a [custom keyboard sample](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/DigitalSign) you can reference.

Comment: @MarianDolinský, they are two different views, and any view could have multiple Textboxes.