# Get textbox reference for viritual keyboard UWP, C#, xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, keyboard, uwp, windowsiot

I have made a virtual keyboard for UWP application that will be used in Windows 10 IoT. For me to be able to use it i need to get a reference to textboxes/fields that is outside my program. I want to be able to read and write from thees text fields but do not know how this can be done.

One example could be if i was on a web page like google and would like to send information from the keyboard to the search bar in google. Or on facebook and would like to send a message. If there is to a textbox in my program then i would know how to send the information. But i also would like to write in all possible textfields like the examples above.

How do i get the keyboard to get the information of where to send it, feel where my mouse pointer has clicked and get a reference of some sort to send my output.

I am sorry if this question has been posted before but as i am in unknown territory i did not know what to search for.

Comment: What do you mean of textboxes/fields that are outside your program?

Comment: For an example if i am on a web site like facebook and would write a message or search for something on google which sites that i could found in my browser. But i do not know how to send the information from my keyboard to the designated fields.

Comment: If you want to enter something without a hardware keyboard you can utilize [on-screen keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960460/windows-iot-core-on-screen-keyboard/41288073#41288073). If you want to get your virtual keyboard functional you can reference [this sample](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/DigitalSign).

Comment: I have come as far as that sample you referenced, But it does not give a solution to what i seek.  I can type in the web browser but not in for example googles search bar. And that is the final step i would like to complete